# How to get unique json object in elasticsearch?

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I have document like:

```
{
            {
            "Task_Id": 3,
            "Subject": "Abhishek1"
            }
            {
            "Task_Id": 3,
            "Subject": "Abhishek2"
            }
            {
            "Task_Id": 2,
            "Subject": "Abhishe3"
            }           
}
```

I want to unique Task_Id when i search for the subject.

I applied following query :

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/clouddemo/_search?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"_source\":[\"Subject\",\"Task_Id\"],\"query\": {\"query_string\" : {\"default_field\" : \"Subject\",\"query\" : \"Abhi\"}},\"aggs\" : {\"distinct_id\" : {\"cardinality\" : {\"field\" : \"Task_Id\"}}}}"  (For the windows)
```

issue:This is returing only distinct count,but i want distinct count.

Expected output:

```
  {
        "Task_Id": 3,
        "Subject": "Abhishek2"
        }
        {
        "Task_Id": 2,
        "Subject": "Abhishe3"
        }(only this two object not count)
```

Comment: can you please clarify if what you want is the count of tasks with same Task_Id?

Comment: I don't want count,i want json object of unique Task_Id with it's subject

Comment: {
        "Task_Id": 3,
        "Subject": "Abhishek2"
        }
        {
        "Task_Id": 2,
        "Subject": "Abhishe3"
        }
The query shoud not repeat the task_id 3 again

Comment: Use terms aggregation instead of cardinality

Comment: aggregation returnig only unique count but i want unique object.